# How do I detect if a specific keyboard button has been released in BGE python

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to know how to detect if a keyboard button has been released in the blender game engine using python, not logic bricks.

So I use this code to detect if a keyboard button is pressed

```
    if (bge.logic.KX_INPUT_ACTIVE == keyboard.events[bge.events.WKEY]):
```

So that right there detects if the "W" key is pressed, but what if I wanted to detect if the "W" key was released, rather than pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You check for `bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_RELEASED`